# How to restrict unauthorized user to have access to different pages in django

Tags: django, security, decorator, login-required

I have this model:

```
class Student(Model):
    user = OneToOneField(CustomUser, on_delete=CASCADE, related_name='student', )
```

and this url:

```
path('students/<int:student_pk>/', student, name='student')
```

and this view:

```
@login_required
def student(request, student_pk):
    return HttpResponse('This is your personal panel')
```

Well, by using login_required decoration I am restricting users that are not logged in to see student panel page. However, other students who are logged in can see other's panels.

How can I restrict them from this?

I can do this:

```
@login_required
def student(request, student_pk):
    student_ins = get_object_or_404(Student, pk=student_pk)
    if student_ins == request.user.student:
        return HttpResponse('This is your personal panel')
    else:
        return HttpResponse('Please do not try to see other students' panels! You are not authorized to do this')
```

However, I prefer to do it in decorator. For example log out the logged in student with primary key pk=1 if he/she entered this in the url: www.example.com/students/2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
from django.contrib.auth import logout

def check_profile(function):
  @wraps(function)
  def wrap(request, *args, **kwargs):
      user = request.user
      student_ins = get_object_or_404(Student, pk=kwargs.get(student_pk))
      if not student_ins == user:
          logout(request)
          return HttpResponse('Please do not try to see other students' panels! You are not authorized to do this')
  return wrap
```

and use that like:

```
@check_profile
@login_required
def student(request, student_pk):
    #...
```

This should do what you want, but keep in mind that **it's not generally a good idea**, unless you have a very special use-case. Basically, what you should do is to have a url like `/profile/` and show the user profile based on the `request.user`; This is much more cleaner way.

Comment: I had simplified the question. I have different user types. I have teacher and student. Teacher can log in and register the student. Then I have this url: ```teachers/2/student/1```  and this url ```students/1```

Comment: So you can keep your `teachers/2/student/<id>` url (and limit that to only teachers), but have `student/profile` for each student's profile

Comment: @AminBa I accepted your request; Thanks for that. Also consider marking the answer as accepted or tell us what's wrong with that.